# Rails enum without corresponding storage / column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following model:

```rb
class Operation < ApplicationRecord
  enum state: [:started, :restarted, :reloaded, :stopped]
end
```

However, the underlying table in the Postgres database does not have `state` column. Although, I can assign value to the `state` attribute and save model instance, `state` just is not saved:

```rb
op = Operation.new state: :started
op.save!
=> true
```

This is a desired behaviour for me, I just want to use it in the same way as `attr_accessor` attributes are used, but with some additional constraints.

The question is, is it fine to use `enum` this way? Or is it an undefined behaviour and could be changed/fixed in the future?

Official documentation does not answer this question https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

UPD: yep, as @ricks says I can achieve the same with:

```rb
attr_accessor :state
validates :state, inclusion: { in: %i[started reloaded restarted stopped] }, allow_nil: true
```

but usage of `enum` is just more convenient for me as it throws exception at assignment time if the value is not from the allowed list.

Comment: What are your required additional constraints? Do you just need the state to be one of those 4 options?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. That is how I do it right now, but I need to use valid? to check state. So I would prefer to use enum if it is safe

Comment: I would probably recommend to use `attr_accessor` since its standard practice, it can be confusing if an error is thrown when assigning the state but not another attribute of the object that might be of an incorrect type, like assigning a string to an attribute that needs to be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the [attributes api](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute).

```
class Operation < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :state
  enum state: [:started, :restarted, :reloaded, :stopped]
end
```

This will give you all the enum exceptions you are looking for (and the rest of the enum methods).

Although it is not in the documentation, it was suggested as a solution in a [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32629).

Comment: Hm, the author of the referenced issue mentions "I'm wrong! I cant use attribute method in ActiveModel::Model..."

Answer (score 0):

you need Enum nothing just do as

```
class Operation < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :state
STATE_KEYS = [:started, :restarted, :reloaded, :stopped].freeze
validates :state, inclusion: { in: STATE_KEYS }
end
```